# Geocode NYC parks based on decription. If no result write NA and continue to other rows

Tags: r, api, geocode

would like to request some help-  want the code to keep on continuing to loop over all other rows if some parks geocode is not found. Currently, If API geocode is not found then entire code stops. Please see the enclosed image.

[image]

```
#looping over park description.
for(i in 1:nrow(distinct_park))
{
  # Print("Working...")
  result <- geocode(distinct_park$park_desc [i], output = "latlona", source = "google", key = "key" )
  distinct_park$lon[i] <- as.numeric(result[1])
  distinct_park$lat[i] <- as.numeric(result[2])
  distinct_park$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[3])
}
```

Comment: why not just test for valid lat/lon values before making the call to `geocode()`? It'd be a simple `if` statement

Comment: Yes, I was thinking if this code can be modified with an if statement -if it finds valid lat-long then gives the results otherwise puts NA and skips to next row instead of stopping.
I am very new to coding - don't know how to modify it to add if statement here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `tryCatch` to map error iterations to assign `NA` to needed columns.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(distinct_park))
{
  # Print("Working...")
  tryCatch({
       result <- geocode(distinct_park$park_desc [i], output = "latlona", 
                         source = "google", key = "key" )
       distinct_park$lon[i] <- as.numeric(result[1])
       distinct_park$lat[i] <- as.numeric(result[2])
       distinct_park$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[3])

  }, error = function(e) { 
       distinct_park$lon[i] <- NA
       distinct_park$lat[i] <- NA
       distinct_park$geoAddress[i] <- NA
  })
}
```